# is there alternative to SUMPRODUCT in excel 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a formal faster than `SUMPRODUCT` in excel 2013 ?

I have this formula in B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YYYY!$A$1:$A$200000=$B$1)*(YYYY!$D$1:$D$200000<=A2)*(YYYY!$O$1:$O$200000="D")*(YYYY!$B$1:$B$200000))
```

I am trying to withdrawn down this formula from B2 to B81000 but it takes ages to calculate ...

please, I need some advice to do that or any alternative way ...

Thank you ..

Moodi

Answer (score 3):

SUMIFS will be faster - try like this

`=SUMIFS(YYYY!$B$1:$B$200000,YYYY!$A$1:$A$200000,$B$1,YYYY!$D$1:$D$200000,"<="&A2,YYYY!$O$1:$O$200000,"D")`

Note that the sum range needs to come first

Comment: Barry, do you have any good links/info on the speed comparison between the two functions?

Comment: I've seen a few comparisons which typically make SUMIFS approx 5x faster than SUMPRODUCT, e.g. this link http://exceluser.com/blog/483/excels-sumifs-or-sumproduct-which-is-faster.html

Comment: @DougGlancy On a large model a couple a years back `SUMIF` was 4x fasted than `SUMPRODUCT` using Charles William's FastExcel